# How to get Images from another system in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am converting image file to blob by using below procedure

```
create or replace function convert_filepath_bytea(p_path text, p_result out bytea)
                   language plpgsql as $$
declare
  l_oid oid;
  r record;
begin
  p_result := '';
  select lo_import(p_path) into l_oid;
  for r in ( select data
             from pg_largeobject
             where loid = l_oid
             order by pageno ) loop
    p_result = p_result || r.data;
  end loop;
  perform lo_unlink(l_oid);
end;$$;
```

for the above procedure i am giving file path as input but that image is in another system then i am getting below error..

```
ERROR:  could not open server file "/home/systemName/files/userInfo/APP_USER_PHOTO_1987_72961_470351_20170703_095023_856.jpg": No such file or directory
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "select lo_import(p_path)"
PL/pgSQL function convert_filepath_bytea(text) line 7 at SQL statement..
```

Thank You..

Comment: Does the postgresql (or the one you are using to run it) user have read access to that directory?

Comment: You are aware that `lo_import` imports files located on the database *server*, not on the client, right?